# Outlook calendar download in webview not displaying the right time in iOS app

Tags: ios, react-native, outlook, uiwebview, react-native-webview

When trying to download an appointment to Outlook calendar on iOS device in webview, the time is completely off. This is not an issue for Android devices or desktop.

The start time is set to device time zone + 1 hour and increments by one hour at the start of a new hour. For example, an appointment downloaded at 2pm device timezone will show start time as 3pm. When the same appointment is downloaded at 3pm device timezone it will show start time as 4pm. The end time is unaffected (unless end time is before start time, in that case the end time will be the start time + 30 minutes).
Has anyone else encountered this?

OS: iOS
OS version: 16.4
react-native version: 0.71.4
react-native-webview version: 11.26.0

I tried making sure the Outlook HTML string had the correct times for iOS device, which it did. I tried formatting the times differently, which didn't fix anything.

The following two images show the expected time and the actual time displayed in the Outlook calendar download:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqAyt.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIPzr.png